# Software to display big matrixes

Tags: excel, matrix

does anyone know any software that could display and save **BIG** matrices?

Currently I am using excel to display generated matrices, but the 16k column limit is too low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the matrices are numerical values you could use a GIS program like QGIS, you would see colors instead of numbers although.

But you can perform calculations as well with raster calculators.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will check it out! No calculations are needed, just the displaying of matrices, problem is that the size of them is far beyond 16k x 16k...

Comment: This is no problem to GIS softwares, but you will see the matrix as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the things you could do in R

```
library(raster)
m <- matrix(1:100, 10, 10)
r <- raster(m)
plot(r)
```